# How do I click individual controls within a list view item without affecting the controls in other list view item?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I'm developing an android application for our music school. I have designed a layout with a list view containing 6 items, the controls in each item are sourced from different layout file.

Layout file containing the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F8AE9F"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/aboutComposer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/msv_songs"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCartTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/cart_total"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvCartTotal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_pay_now" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstMSVSongs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:focusable="false" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout file that is the source of controls for each list view item

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tvViewSample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFilmPoster"
            android:layout_width="75sp"
            android:layout_height="75sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSongName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvFilmName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvFilmName"
            android:text="@string/dummy"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvYearReleased"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvSongName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvSongName"
            android:text="@string/dummy"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvYearReleased"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvYearReleased"
            android:text="@string/dummy"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFilmName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgFilmPoster"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="@string/dummy"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAddCart"
            android:layout_width="35sp"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_to_cart"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgView"
            android:src="@drawable/add_to_cart"
            android:tag = "@string/add_to_cart" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="35sp"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgFilmPoster"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPlay"
            android:src="@drawable/view_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPlay"
            android:layout_width="35sp"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgView"
            android:contentDescription="@string/play_mp3"
            android:src="@drawable/play" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java code for loading data for individual list items and handling image view click events

```
    private List<Song> msvSongs = new ArrayList<Song>();    

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.msv_music_sheets);
            populateSongsList();
            populateSongsListView();
        }

        private void populateSongsList() {
            msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_ayirathil_oruvan,"Ayirathil Oruvan","Adho Andha Paravai Pola","1965",150,R.raw.msv_adho_andha_paravai_pola_ao));
            msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_karuppu_panam,"Karuppu Panam","Aadavaralaam","1964",150,R.raw.msv_aadavaralaam_kp));
            msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_paalum_pazhamum,"Paalum Paazhamum","Aalayamaniyin Oosai","1961",150,R.raw.msv_aalayamaniyin_oosai_pp));
            msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_paava_mannippu,"Paava Mannipu","Athaan Ennathan","1961",150,R.raw.msv_athaan_ennathaan_pm));
            msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_periya_idhuthu_pen,"Periya Idhuthu Pen","Andru Vandhadhadhum Adhey Nila","1963",175,R.raw.msv_andru_vandhadhum_adhey_nila_pip));
            msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_puthiya_paravai,"Pudhiya Paravai","Enge Nimmadhi","1964",250,R.raw.msv_enge_nimmadhi_pparavai));
            //msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_server_sundaram,"Server Sundaram","Avalukku Enna Azhagiya Mugam","1964",150,R.raw.msv_avalukkenna_azhagiamugham_ss));
        }

        private void populateSongsListView() {
            ArrayAdapter<Song> msvSongs = new MSVSongsAdapter();
            ListView songsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMSVSongs);
            songsList.setAdapter(msvSongs);

        }


private class MSVSongsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song>{        
        public MSVSongsAdapter(){
            super(MsvSongs.this, R.layout.songs_view, msvSongs);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.songs_view, parent, false);         
            }

            for(int i=0;i<msvSongs.size();i++){
                //Find a song to display                
                final Song currentSong = msvSongs.get(position);

                //Fill the FilmPoster View
                ImageView filmPoster = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFilmPoster);
                filmPoster.setImageResource(currentSong.getFilmImageID());  

                //Fill the FilmName View
                TextView filmName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFilmName);
                filmName.setText(currentSong.getMovieName());

                //Fill the SongName View
                TextView songName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
                songName.setText(currentSong.getSongName());

                //Fill the YearReleased View
                TextView yearReleased = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvYearReleased);
                yearReleased.setText(currentSong.getYearReleased());

                //Fill the Price View
                TextView songPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
                songPrice.setText("Rs. "+currentSong.getSongPrice());

                //Fill the Play MP3 View
                final ImageView viewMP3 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlay);               

                viewMP3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                 


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String contentDesc = (String) viewMP3.getContentDescription();                      
                        if(contentDesc.contains("Play")){   
                            if (mp3Player != null && mp3Player.isPlaying()){
                                    Toast.makeText(MsvSongs.this, "Stop the previous song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                 
                            }else{
                                    mp3Player=MediaPlayer.create(MsvSongs.this, currentSong.getmp3File());
                                    mp3Player.start();
                                    viewMP3.setImageResource(drawable.stop);                            
                                    viewMP3.setContentDescription("Stop MP3");                                  
                            }                                                   
                        }else{              
                            mp3Player.pause();
                            mp3Player.stop();
                            mp3Player.release();
                            mp3Player=null;
                            viewMP3.setImageResource(drawable.play);                                
                            viewMP3.setContentDescription("Play MP3");
                        }

                    }
                });
```

When I click the Play button of a song inside a list view, it plays the song and changes the Play image to Stop image. But it also changes the Play image to Stop image of other list view item.

Could you please advice what is wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
private class MSVSongsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    private MediaPlayer mp3Player;

    public MSVSongsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Song> songList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.songList = songList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return songList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.songs_view,null);
            holder.filmPoster = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgFilmPoster);
            holder.viewMP3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewMP3);
            holder.filmName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filmName);
            holder.songName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
            holder.yearReleased = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yearReleased);
            holder.songPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songPrice);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.filmPoster.setImageResource(songList.get(position).getFilmImageID());
        holder.viewMP3.setImageResource(songList.get(position).getFilmImageID());
        holder.filmName.setText(songList.get(position).getMovieName());
        holder.songName.setText(songList.get(position).getSongName());
        holder.yearReleased.setText(songList.get(position).getYearReleased());
        holder.songPrice.setText("Rs. " + songList.get(position).getSongPrice());

        holder.viewMP3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String contentDesc = (String) songList.get(position).getContentDescription();
                if (contentDesc.contains("Play")) {
                    if (mp3Player != null && mp3Player.isPlaying()) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Stop the previous song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        mp3Player = MediaPlayer.create(context, songList.get(position).getmp3File());
                        mp3Player.start();
                        ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
                        ((ImageView)v).setContentDescription("Stop MP3");
                    }
                } else {
                    mp3Player.pause();
                    mp3Player.stop();
                    mp3Player.release();
                    mp3Player = null;
                    ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    ((ImageView)v).setContentDescription("Play MP3");
                }

            }
        });
        return null;
    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView filmPoster;
        ImageView viewMP3;
        TextView filmName;
        TextView songName;
        TextView yearReleased;
        TextView songPrice;
    }
}
```